# Sequential numbers in distributed word

Tags: nhibernate, distributed, sequences

We are building order processing system. We have a cluster of processing servers. We need to assign readable numbers to the orders (e.g. ORD-000001, ORD-000002).

Main problem that this is hard for us to implement system wide lock. I am thinking about schemas with lock expiration. But everything comes in mind still have bottlenecks.

We are approaching DDD, so direct access to database is hard. We are using NHibernate. And we use UnitOfWork.

Pls, help with some ideas. Every idea will be valuable. Any links to something to read on topic?

UPDATE:
I want to stress, that I need sequential numbers. And so cannot use hi/low algorithms. At this time I am ivestigating scenario when

1. I assign "probably good number";
2. Push it to database;
3. If fail, try to assign another "probably good number";
4. If success, commit;

But I cannot find goot technology for it.

Comment: I think about idea of using MPI (see boost and C# implementations), but not sure if this will help. One of the ideas there is that each communicator knows its own rank (i.e. it's Nth to appear in distributed env). Not sure if this helps, but I believe it ranks as "some" and "every" idea ;-)

Comment: BTW, do you have single database or many across the servers? If it's single, why can't use use database's autoincremented PK? (if you can't use Orders table, use special OrdersPK table, insert row, and get your unique sequential number). If they're multiple, how do you test "push to database" for failure?

Comment: queen3, I cannot use PK, mainly because we use multi tenancy. We use the same database to store order for multiple users. And users have to have difference sequences.

Comment: Couldn't you do something like, grab the highest order number from all existing orders for a given customer and then just add one?  Couldn't you just stick that on the DB as a stored procedure or something for whenever you create a new order record?  I'm not a DB guy, just taking stabs in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to make sure all the orders have unique numbers, but without having a central location that coordinates the number distribution?

Here are two options for you.

1. Let's say you expect to have, at most, ten servers in any realistic period of time.  Have each server hand out sequential numbers of the form ORD-XXXXXN.  N is the number of the server.  So server 0 hands out ORD-000000, ORD-000010, ORD-000020, etc.  Server 6 hands out ORD-000006, ORD-000016, ORD-000026, etc.
2. Hand out blocks of numbers, 10000 at a time.  Each server uses up all numbers in a block before retrieving more from a little server running in the background somewhere.  The little server just runs through all the blocks, one by one, passing them out one at a time.  The first block to be handed out is 0-9999, the second is 10000-19999, the third is 20000-29999, etc.

Comment: Use the second you never know when you'll get more than 10 servers

Comment: Does it really solve the problem of sequential numbers among all servers? S1 does 00, then 10, then S2 does 06... ops, out of sequence. And if we can use "small background server", why not just place SQL table with autoincremented PK or a shared file with number on it.... Nevertheles, an interesting problem/question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use hi/low algorithms. I need sequential numbers. At this time I am investigating options how to reduce roundtrips and latency with central location. But I do not like the idea of central location.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that the sequential nature of the numbers was so important.

If you want to guarantee sequential numbers, you need something that is going to hand them out at a central source.  Otherwise, there's no way to be sure that the number you just handed out hasn't been used by someone else.  But if having a central source isn't a problem, why not just have the database automatically put in index numbers, or something?

Comment: Having central source means additional roundtrips. Also this means bottlenecks, as we have to lock sequence source. So ProcessB, will wait until ProcessB is completed. We want to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, if you really use single database, why can't you just

```
CREATE TABLE OrderNumbers (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Dummy VARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO OrderNumbers (Dummy) SELECT ''
SELECT 'ORDER_N' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @@IDENTITY) AS NewOrderNumber
```

UPDATE: Even if you have different users (multi tenancy), the PK will work if your sequential number doesn't have to be +1 - i.e. you can have 1, 4, 10, not only 1, 2, 3.

UPDATE: or, as jprete suggested, do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerOrderNumber (ID INT, CustomerID INT)
CREATE FUNCTION GetMaxId ( @mycustomerid INT ) RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN
 DECLARE @maxid INT
 SET @maxid = SELECT ID FROM CustomerOrderNumber WHERE CustomerID = @mycustomerid
 SET @maxid = @maxid + 1
 UPDATE CustomerOrderNumber SET ID = @maxid
 RETURN @maxid
END
```

Comment: Last solution, is one we are using for now. We cannot live with it, because of gaps. I think if we will not have better solution we will live with something like this, but with lock mechanizm.

Comment: I don't understand, there should be no gaps. You increase numbers one by one for each customer. And of course locking is required. Well, another solution would be "table per customer" - this is used by MANY companies, e.g. MS ;-) - but I never recommend it. Anyway, with central DB server this is not really an interesting problem ;-)